# Returning nodeset based on two other nodes being equal

Tags: xml, xpath

I am trying to return a specific nodeset based on the value of one node = another node.

The expression `//*[local-name()='jms-listener']/@busidref=//*[local-name()='jms-bus']/@busid` returns a boolean from

```
<providers>
      <jms-provider name="JBossMQ" connection-factory="ConnectionFactory">
          <jms-bus busid="quickstartGwChannel">
              <jms-message-filter
                  dest-type="QUEUE"
                  dest-name="queue/quickstart_helloworld_Request_gw"
               />
          </jms-bus>
          <jms-bus busid="quickstartEsbChannel">
              <jms-message-filter
                  dest-type="QUEUE"
                  dest-name="queue/quickstart_helloworld_Request_esb"
              />
          </jms-bus>

      </jms-provider>
  </providers>

  <services>
    <service 
        category="FirstServiceESB" 
        name="SimpleListener" 
        description="Hello World">
        <listeners>
            <jms-listener name="JMS-Gateway"
                busidref="quickstartGwChannel"
                is-gateway="true"
            />
            <jms-listener name="helloWorld"
                          busidref="quickstartEsbChannel"
            />
        </listeners>
        <actions mep="OneWay">
               <action name="action1" 
                class="org.jboss.soa.esb.samples.quickstart.helloworld.MyJMSListenerAction" 
                process="displayMessage" 
                />      
                <action name="action2" class="org.jboss.soa.esb.actions.SystemPrintln">
                  <property name="printfull" value="false"/>
                </action>
                <!-- The next action is for Continuous Integration testing -->
                <action name="testStore" class="org.jboss.soa.esb.actions.TestMessageStore"/>
        </actions>
    </service>
  </services>
```

I need it to return quickstartGwChannel.

Comment: You said - *I am trying to return a specific nodeset based on the value of one node = another node.*.. My question is - what are *one node* and *another node* ?

Answer (score 0):

The conditional check needs to be a property of the node. Try this:

```
//jms-listener[@busidref=//jms-bus/@busid]/@busidref
```

Which returns:

```
quickstartGwChannel
quickstartEsbChannel
```

The xpath is saying to find a `jms-listener` node whose `@busidref` attribute is equal to any `jms-bus` node's `@busid` attribute. Then return the `@busidref` attribute values of those nodes.

If you need to use the `local-name`, the above xpath would be:

```
//*[local-name()='jms-listener'][@busidref=//*[local-name()='jms-bus']/@busid]/@busidref
```

If you want to also check that the is-gateway attribute is also true, add it to the list of predicates:

```
//*[local-name()='jms-listener'][@busidref=//*[local-name()='jms-bus']/@busid][@is-gateway='true']/@busidref
```

Comment: To test it I changed <jms-listener name="helloWorld" busidref="quickstartEsbChannel" to busidref="X12" so that it would not match the jms-bus.  It still returns both.  So, it looks like the expression is doing the samething as //@busidref.

Comment: This works.  //*[@is-gateway='true' and @busidref=//*[local-name()='jms-bus']/@busid]/@busidref.  However, it turns out all the work is being done by is-gateway='true' and produces the same result if used alone.

Comment: Sorry, I cannot reproduce your problem. When I changed the busidref="quickstartEsbChannel" to busidref="X12", the xpath only returned the "quickstartGwChannel" - see [this test online](http://www.xpathtester.com/saved/06b7813c-ab5e-44ba-a13c-2c632963fa42).

Comment: Perhaps problem is tester I was using.  I was using http://www.whitebeam.org/library/guide/TechNotes/xpathtestbed.rhtm  Thanks.  And for pointing to better tester.

Comment: I think the issue is the tester. Did you try the xpath in your actual application?

Comment: Yes, after testing it worked.  How would I modify it to include another predicate?  I want to key on the is-gateway="true" found in the jms-listener.  Both have to be true to get what I want.

Comment: You can add that predicate to the list of other predicates - see updated answer.